# Linq multi level inner join

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 diffferent entities:

`E1, E2, E3`

E1 has a property that is an ObservableCollection of E2.
E2 has a property that is an ObservableCollection of E3.

And with a linq query, I want to get all E3 based on E1 I got as starting point.

I tried something like that :

```
Query = Query.Where<E3>(i => E1.E2List.Select(ep => ep.E3List.Select(ai => ai.id))
             .Contains(i.id));
```

Basically meaning : getting all E3 where it's id is in the list of E3 in the lists of E2 from E1

But as you guess, this doesn't work.

```
My starting point is this :
//make the array 
E3[] array;
//get all E3 datas
IQueryable<E3> Query = DBSetE3.AsQueryable();
```

And I must have all the results in my array

So my result should be : getting in array, all E3 objects that are linked into E2 that are contains into E1, based on E1.

For example :

```
Entity 1| List of E2
E1 | E2A, E2B

Entity 2 | List of E3
E2B | E3C, E3D
E2A | E3E, E3F
```

When I search for E3 linked to E1, I must get E3C, E3D,E3E,E3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var e1Ids = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
var e3s = DBSetE1.AsQueryable().Where(e => e1Ids.Contains(e.Id))
                               .SelectMany(e => e.E2List)
                               .SelectMany(e => e.E3List);
```

Basically, you filter all the E1's based on your input. Then you want to `SelectMany` (which flattens the the result `[[1,2],[3,4]]` into `[1,2,3,4]`) to grab the E2s. Then you `SelectMany` it's E3s.

Comment: This works pretty well, unless I removed an object from E1 and recalculate without doing a SaveChanges on my datacontext. And the wierdest thing is (from my test datas) : I remove E2A from E1, then calculate. When I check E1, there is only E2B (as expected), but `.SelectMany(e => e.E2List)` brings `E3C, E3D, E3E, E3F` while it should only get `E3E, E3F`.
If I save automatically it works perfectly, but that is not quite good to automatically save. Any idea to complete the answer (still, I consider your answer as accepted because it works fine)?

Comment: @Zaphod In this case, you would need to run the query in memory rather than hitting the database again. By that, I mean you'd write `e3s.Where(` rather than `DBSetE1.AsQueryable().Where(`. This way it'd be evaluated in memory, rather then reading the stale data in the database. That is of course, assuming `e3s` has been materialized (ie, it's not `IQueryable<>`, but should be `IList<>`, `IEnumerable<>`, etc)